# Play Framework 2.1.2 -> 2.1.3: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.1

I've just moved from Play Framework version 2.1.2 to 2.1.3. In my case it lives in **C:\Play\current_version**, so the PATH is always unchanged.

In both versions I can do **play clean compile** and **play run** successfully from console. But when I do **run** from IDEA with version **2.1.3** I have:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
```

and bubble:

```
Error running PROJECT_NAME:
Cannot find Play 2 install dir
```

Where to dig?

**UPDATE:**

1st thing: everything compiles both by 2.1.2 and 2.1.3 both in console and IDEA. I have problem when I'm trying to run the app by 2.1.3 from IDEA.

I've found that 2.1.3 is trying to use **C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_22** instead of **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25** or **C:\Program Files\Java\jre7**. Now I've renamed the folder to **C:\Program Files (x86)\Java_not** and I have an error when trying to run 2.1.3 from IDEA:

```
C:\Play\current_version\play.bat
Error: could not open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_22\lib\i386\jvm.cfg'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What I don't understand is where 2.1.3 takes path to **C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_22**. System **path** variable contains only **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin**.

This wrong path is probably configured somewhere in IDEA (since from console 2.1.3 runs successfully) and surprisingly affects only 2.1.3, but not 2.1.2.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I take it you can run the app from the IDE with v2.1.2.  When you flip to 2.1.3, have you tried cleaning the project through the command line to see if that works for you.  Also, what JDK version s being used by the IDE (and what's the default one on your computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not related to Play Framework at all.

Solution was found here: http://jaykhimani.blogspot.ru/2012/09/error-could-not-open-cprogram.html

**java.exe**, **javaw.exe** and **javaws.exe** should be deleted from

**C:\Windows\SysWOW64**
and
**C:\Windows\System32**

Comment: I still have the problem "Cannot find Play 2 install dir" after deleting those files... going back to 2.1.2 for now

Comment: In IDEA go to "Run -> Edit configurations" and fill "Use non-default Play 2 install dir" field of your running config.

Comment: @cosmolev I tried this before I read your comment and it worked. For me I had no issues running created projects, just inherited projects (2.2.1 -> 2.2.2/3)

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes up if you try to run class files compiled with one java version with another one. You can set the java version to compile and run in your applications.conf and it should be the same which is defined as standard for your system (most often 1.6, 1.7 on modern macs)

Search for the following line in your application.conf:

```
'java.source=1.6'
```

If its not present, add it. If its present, make sure it is set to the version your environment is using.
Finally, clean and recompile - it should work now.