# "Cannot find Play 2 install dir" in Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework

I'm trying to use Play 2.2.2 and I'm getting the following red bubble when I try to launch a run configuration of Play 2 plug-in in Idea:

"Cannot find Play 2 install dir"

What is exactly Play 2 install dir? I've tried to use directory of Play Activator, Play classic install, my project directory, putting all these to PATH, etc. but nothing works. Play documentation is silent regarding this. It's even more stranger that 2 other developers on our team doesn't face this issue - they have nothing in the Play Home directory in Idea's Setting and still everything works fine them (on Windows, MacOS).

My project compiles and runs from the Play console. OS: Linux.

PS: This is not a duplicate of [Play Framework 2.1.2 -> 2.1.3: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422664/play-framework-2-1-2-2-1-3-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have to run build.sh in play/framework folder (where you unzip play 2.2.2 classic), and then execute "compile" command. After a successful build it's recognized as Play home by Idea Play 2 plugin.

Comment: I get this error with a 2.2.1 inherited project. Anything I create doesn't seem to be affected. Which I find odd, but this didn't solve the issue.